# Show that if some equation is solvable modulo $p$, then it is also solvable modulo $p^n$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

> Show that if $x^2=a$ is solvable modulo $p$, then it is also solvable modulo $p^n$ for all positive integers $n.$  (Note that $p$ is prime, not necessarily >2, and $a$ is not required to be divisible by $p$.)

My work, so far:

By assumption, $x^2 =a$ is solvable modulo $p$ - call the solution $x = k$.

Then $\frac {x^2 - a}{p} \in \mathbb{Z}$,which implies

$$k^2 - a = mp$$

for $m, k \in \mathbb{Z}$

Now I'm trying to show the next implication, namely that there exists some $x$ such that

$$\frac{x^2-a}{p^2} \in \mathbb{Z}$$

Any comments or suggestions are welcome.

Thanks,

Comment: See [Hensel's Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hensel%27s_lemma)

Comment: $x^2 = 3$ is solvable mod $3$, not solvable mod $3^n$ for any $n>1$.  You should adjust the statement of the problem.

Comment: @user58865 I mean that the problem, as you have stated it, is **false** and therefore cannot be proven.  It can be adjusted so that it is true, but we are not mind readers so it's your job to go back and check if you omitted any details from the question.  One reasonable possibility is to require that $a$ is not divisible by $p$, and that $p$ be a prime $>2$.  But again, **not** mind readers, and note that the assumptions that you're missing are almost as long as the question itself.

Comment: @user58865 No problem, this is very easy once you focus on the right thing.  In order for $x^2 - 3$ to be divisible by $3^n$ it must be divisible by $3$, but for this to happen, $x$ itself must be divisible by $3$ (this follows from uniqueness of prime factorization).  However, then $x^2$ is in fact divisible by $9$, so $x^2 - 3$ is not a multiple of $9$.  This proves that $x^2 - 3$ cannot be divisible by $9$ or any higher power of $3$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To solve $x^2\equiv a\pmod{p}$, you need to find an integer $n$ such that $p$ divides $n^2 - a$: in other words, $n^2\equiv a\pmod{p}$. If you have such an integer $n$, you want to find $n'$ such that $n'^2\equiv a\pmod{p^2}$.

If you already know that $n^2\equiv a\pmod{p}$, so maybe try looking for an $n'$ of the form $n' = n + pm$? Substitute $n + pm$ for $n'$ in $n'^2$, and start reducing modulo $p^2$, maybe even consider the quantity $(n+pm)^2 - a$ modulo $p^2$. Remember that if $p$ is prime, then as long as $p$ doesn't divide $x$, you can find an integer $y$ such that $xy\equiv 1\pmod{p}$ ($p$ divides $xy - 1$). Can you generalize lifting a solution modulo $p$ to a solution modulo $p^2$ to lifting from $p^n$ to $p^{n+1}$? What happens if $p = 2$? What if $p$ isn't prime? What about the case $a = 0$?

To see this concretely, maybe note that $x^2\equiv -1\pmod{5}$ has a solution: namely, $x = 2$ since $x^2\equiv 2^2\equiv 4\equiv -1\pmod{5}$ (remember that $4\equiv -1\pmod{5}$ means $5$ divides $4 - (-1) = 5$, which is true). Now, try to find $n$ such that $(2 + 5n)^2\equiv -1\pmod{25}$. The algebra involved here will be the same as in the general case, but working with a concrete example often helps me really see what's happening without getting lost in the symbols and abstraction.

EDIT:

Let's proceed with the example $x^2\equiv -1\pmod{5^n}$. We know that $2^2\equiv -1\pmod{5}$, and we want to find $n'$ such that $(n')^2\equiv -1\pmod{25}$. Per the suggestion, we set $n' = 2 + 5n$. It follows that
\begin{align*}
(2 + 5n)^2 - (-1) &\equiv 4 + 4\cdot 5n + 25n^2 + 1\pmod{25}\\
&\equiv 5 + 4\cdot 5n\pmod{25}
\end{align*}
Then $5 + 4\cdot 5n\equiv 0\pmod{25}$ is equivalent to $1 + 4n\equiv 0\pmod{5}$, which is easily solved: $4n\equiv -1\equiv 4\pmod{5}$, so $n = 1$ works. Let's double check:
$$
(2 + 5\cdot 1)^2 \equiv 7^2\equiv 49\equiv 50 - 1\equiv -1\pmod{25}.
$$
Note that this was possible because $25\equiv 0\pmod{25}$, so the $n^2$ dropped out and we didn't have to solve a quadratic again, only a linear equation (which was solvable, since we had one unknown which took values in a field ($\Bbb Z/5\Bbb Z$).

As for why you might choose $2 + 5n$ as a "guess," you can imagine that looking modulo small powers of $5$ is like approximating a solution, and the higher a power you look at, the closer you get to the actual solution. To see this, imagine that $5$ is actually a very small number, say $5$ has absolute value less than $1$. Then $5^2$ is even smaller, so you might think of this as analogous to looking at an equation in $\Bbb R$ and trying to solve it up to some fixed decimal place, after which you cut off the rest and pretend the smaller places don't exist. So solving modulo $5^n$ is like finding the first $n$ digits of a solution, but we can algebraically use our first $n$ digits and the arithmetic of $\Bbb Z/5^n\Bbb Z$ to find the $n+1$st digit. This is made precise via the notion of $p$-adic numbers, which were inspired (partially) by this very lifting problem.

A less high-brow reason you might choose $(2 + 5n)$ as a guess is that if $k$ is a solution modulo $p^2$, you can write $k = k_1 + pk_2$, where $0\leq k_1,k_2\leq p-1$, so $k^2\equiv a\pmod{p^2}$ and $k^2\equiv (k_1 + pk_2)^2\equiv k_1^2\equiv a\pmod{p}$, so that any solution modulo $p^2$ gives you a solution modulo $p$ with the same value modulo $p$ as the original solution (look modulo $p$ instead of modulo $p^2$).

FINAL EDIT (spoilers ahead, if someone knows how to render all this in a spoiler box feel free to do so):

> ! Suppose $k_1^2\equiv a\pmod{p}$ and that $2k_1\not\equiv 0\pmod{p}$. Then we claim $k_2^2\equiv a\pmod{p^2}$, where $k_2 = k_1 - p\frac{k_1^2 - a}{p}(2k_1)^{-1}$, where $(2k_1)^{-1}$ is an integer $x$ such that $(2k_1)x + py = 1$ for some integer $y$ (this exists, because $p$ and $2k_1$ are relatively prime). Indeed, recall that $(k_1^2 - a)/p$ is an integer, because $k_1^2\equiv a\pmod{p}$, so that
>   \begin{align*}
> k_2^2&\equiv \left(k_1 - p\frac{k_1^2 - a}{p}(2k_1)^{-1}\right)^2\pmod{p^2}\\
> &\equiv k_1^2 - \color{blue}{p 2k_1(2k_1)^{-1}\frac{k_1^2 - a}{p}} + \color{red}{p^2\left(\frac{k_1^2 - a}{p}\right)^2\left((2k_1)^{-1}\right)^2}\pmod{p^2}\\
> &\equiv k_1^2 - \color{blue}{p\cdot 1\cdot\frac{k_1^2 - a}{p}} + \color{red}{0}\pmod{p^2}\\
> &\equiv k_1^2 - \color{blue}{(k_1^2 - a)}\pmod{p^2}\\
> &\equiv 0 + a\pmod{p^2}\\
> &\equiv a\pmod{p^2}.
> \end{align*}
>   The motivation for this choice of $k_2$ comes from starting with setting $k_2 = k_1 + px$ and solving for $x$, given that $k_2^2\equiv a\pmod{p^2}$. Lifting a solution modulo $p^n$ to a solution modulo $p^{n+1}$ is almost identical and the details are left to the reader as an exercise.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45423/discussion-on-answer-by-stahl-show-that-if-some-equation-is-solvable-modulo-p).

Answer (score 3):

I am proceeding with the assumption that $ p $ is prime. The following statement is the simplest form of Hensel's lemma:

**Theorem (Hensel's lemma).** Let $ f(X) \in \mathbf Z[X] $ be a polynomial with a root $ \alpha $ in $ \mathbf Z/p\mathbf Z $ such that $ f(\alpha) = 0 $ and $ f'(\alpha) \neq 0 $ ($f' $ is the formal derivative of $ f $). Then, $ f(X) $ has a unique root modulo every $ p^n $ for $ n \geq 1 $ which is congruent to $ \alpha $ modulo $ p $.

The proof is simple and proceeds by induction, you may find an argument in [this wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hensel%27s_lemma).

To see why this resolves our problem, let $ p $ be an odd prime. Then, the formal derivative of $ X^2 - a $ is $ 2X $, which does not vanish unless $ X = 0 $. Thus, Hensel's lemma kicks in and gives us a root in $ \mathbf Z_p $, that is, a root modulo every $ p^n $. However, we have a problem if $ p = 2 $: the formal derivative is then zero, since $ 2 = 0 $ in characteristic 2. Indeed, for example, $ 3 $ is a perfect square modulo $ 2 $, but it is not a perfect square modulo $ 4 $.

This has to do with the structure of the group $ \mathbf Z_2^{\times} $ - in short, an odd integer is a perfect square modulo every $ 2^n $ if and only if it is a perfect square modulo $ 8 $. In comparison, the result for odd primes is simpler, as we have seen above.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, @Starfall, although I feel it's a bit too much machinery and I wonder whether there's a way to show it without applying Hensel's lemma...

Comment: Hensel's lemma is an elementary result - it is just a simple induction. I feel like the intended solution is just a proof of Hensel's lemma in this special case.

Comment: [it is a bit unclear, but explains that](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hensel%27s_lemma#Derivation) $f'(\alpha)$ comes in when writing the polynomial $f(\alpha+p^k X)$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{p^{k+m}}[X]$. In $\mathbb{Z}[X]$ : $f(\alpha+ p^k X) = f(\alpha) + f'(\alpha) p^k  X + p^{2k} X^2 g(X)$ for some polynomial $g(X)$, so that $f(\alpha+ p^k \beta) \equiv f(\alpha) + p^k f'(\alpha)  \beta  \bmod p^{k+m}, m \le k$  @user58865

Answer (score 0):

Yes, $p$ denotes a prime number.  To say that $x^2 = a$ is solvable modulo $p$ means that the congruence $x^2 \equiv a \mod p$ has a solution.

Comment: What in the problem statement convinces you that $p$ must be a prime?  Yes, it often is defined that way, but not always.

Comment: $p$ should be prime in this case...

Suppose $p = 6$; then $x^2 \equiv 3 \mod 6$ is solvable with $x \equiv 3 \mod 6$, but $x^2 \equiv 3 \mod 6^2$ is not solvable.

Comment: Hi @cat - how do you know $x^2 \equiv 3 \pmod{6^2}$ is not solvable?  I can see that by plugging in numbers but how could I claim that rigorously?  Thanks,

Comment: @RossMillikan Because otherwise this would be a horrible choice of notation.

Comment: Hi @Ted, I revised my question just a bit to show my current progress.  I'm pretty stuck.  Can you offer another hint? :)

Comment: @user58865 Just check all 36 congruence classes (or just $0, 1, \dots, 18$ since $(-x)^2 \equiv x^2$)

Comment: Hi @cat, ah, I see what you mean.  Do you have a further hint for how I can proceed with this problem?  I've been stuck for awhile now...thanks Cat,

Comment: @user58865 I would try to follow Stahl's method, he/she gives some good hints there. The general proof was use mathematical induction, but first try to prove the cases ``1 implies 2", that is $x^2 \equiv a \mod p$ solvable implies $x^2 \equiv a \mod p^2$ solvable. That will help with the inductive step.

Comment: @Ted My apologies for downvoting without checking the question history.

Comment: Hi @cat, if $k$ is a solution modulo p, so $\frac {x^2-a}{p}=m$ I have now tried the numbers $x$ = $k+p$, $k+pm$, $k+p^2m$ and $k^2+p^2m^2$...to check whether $\frac {x^2 -a}{p^2} \in \mathbb{Z}$  This brute-force approach hasn't worked yet, unfortunately.  What do you think?  Thanks,

Comment: Suppose $k^2 \equiv a \mod p$. You should consider $k + pm$ for $m \in \mathbb Z$ as possible solutions for $x^2 \equiv a \mod p^2$; this is a natural consideration because $k + pm \equiv k \mod p$ and this is by assumption a solution to $x^2 \equiv a \mod p$. Now you need to choose the $m$ wisely, so that $k+ pm$ is indeed a solution to $x^2 \equiv a \mod p^2$. 

Again, this is (more or less) what @Stahl is describing.

Answer (score 0):

$p$ does not generally have to be prime, although often it is chosen as the letter to represent the modulus to emphasize that it is prime.  If it is required to be prime, the author should say so.  If I want generic naturals, I start with $n,m$, but if I need more then $p,q$ are next even if primality is not required. In this example, $3^2=9 \equiv 3\pmod {6}$. $6$ is not prime, but we can say $x^2=3$ is solvable $\bmod 6$. This example shows that the statement requires something else (like $p$ being prime) as $x^2=3$ has no solution $\bmod {36}$.  Just try all the cases.

Comment: Hi @RossMillikan, in trying to imply the solvability modulo $p^2$, if $k$ is a solution, modulo p, so that $\frac {x^2-a}{p}=m$, I have now tried the numbers $x$ = $k+p$, $k+pm$, $k+p^2m$ and $k^2+p^2m^2$...to check whether $\frac {x^2 -a}{p^2} \in \mathbb{Z}$  This brute-force approach hasn't worked yet, unfortunately.  What do you think?  Thanks,